# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal' to type 'Cdma.Web.Helpers.CrossCutting.Security.CustomPrincipal'

Tags: c#

I wanted to cast from this RolePrincipal to my customPrincipal, but i am getting this error ,here is my code.

```
var identity = ((CustomPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User).CustomIdentity;
```

Please can someone help me out with this.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what's wrong..

Answer (score 0):

That is because your CustomPrincipal is neither the type nor a base type of HttpContext.Current.User.

Comment: Example: you cannot cast Apple to Banana or Vegetable, but you can cast it to Fruit or Object, since Apple is a Fruit and an Object. In this example "is a" means "inherits from".